# Removing lines from a string + old entries from a Dictionary in C#

Tags: c#, dictionary

I have a Dictionary the first string, the key's, must never change.. it cant be deleted or anything.. but the value, i keep adding lines, and lines, and lines to the values.. i just create new lines with \r\n or \r .. and im just wondering what would be the easiest way to retain just the last 50 lines. and delete anything over the 50 lines.. im doing this because when i return it i have to put the values through a char array, and go through each letter, and this can be slow if there is too much data. any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of concatenating the lines, use a `Dictionary<string, List<string>>`. When you are about to add a string to the list you can check the count and remove the first string if the list already has 50 strings:

```
List<string> list;
if (!theDictionary.TryGetValue(key, out list)) {
  theDictionary.Add(list = new List<string>());
}
if (list.Count == 50) {
  list.RemoveAt(0);
}
list.Add(line);
```

Comment: This is impossible because of the way my program reads the string.

Comment: @Guffa: Well, that would be possible, but in the end, id still need to compile it into one big string to use it with my program. so id basically be going around in a circle. from a big string, to a string list, to a big string again and i fail to see the point of this?

Comment: @sniperX: Yes, you would have to concatenate the strings for the final result, but that is still less work than removing the first line from a string even once.

Answer (score 2):

Guffa's general idea is right - your data structure should reflect what you actually want, which is a *list of strings* rather than a single string. The concept of "the last 50 lines" is pretty obviously to do with a collection rather than a single string, even if you've originally read it that way.

However, I'd suggest using a [`LinkedList<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/he2s3bh7.aspx) rather than a `List<T>`: every time you remove the first element of a `List<T>`, everything else has to shuffle up. `List<T>` is great for giving random access and not too bad at adding to the end, but sucks for removing from the start. `LinkedList<T>` is great at giving you iterator access, adding to / removing from the start, and adding to / removing from the end. It's a better fit. (If you really wanted to go to town you could even write your own fixed-size circular buffer type which encapsulated the logic for you; this would give the best of both worlds, in the situation where you don't want to be able to expand beyond a certain size.)

Regarding your comments to Guffa's answer: it's pretty common to convert input into a form which is more appropriate for processing, then convert it back to the original format for output. The reason why you do it is precisely the "more appropriate" bit. You don't want to have to parse the string for line breaks as part of the "updating the dictionary" action, IMO. In particular, it sounds like you're currently *introducing* the idea of "lines" where the original text is just being read in as strings. You're effectively creating your own "collection" class backed by a string, by delimiting strings with line breaks. That's inefficient, error-prone, and much harder to manage than using the built-in collections. It's easy to perform the conversion to a line-break-delimited string at the end if you want it, but it sounds like you're doing it way too early.